# Прочитарий комментарий из подписи КриптоПро

Tags: c#, цифровая-подпись, криптопро

У меня есть файл с открепленной подписью сделанной КриптоПро.

В подписи есть комментарий (Oid 1.2.643.2.45.1.1.1) типа BMPString, извлекаю подпись с помощью C#:

```
Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(signedAttrValue.RawData)
```

На выходе получаю нужный текст, но первым знаком всегда идет знак Ḏ (U+1e0e) и т.п.
Вопрос что это за знаки?

Answer (score 0):

Знак Ḏ (U+1e0e) и другие подобные знаки, которые вы получаете в начале вывода из кодировки BMPString, являются результатом использования кодировки UTF-16BE (Unicode Transformation Format - 16-bit Big Endian) для преобразования строки из байтов.

В C# метод Encoding.BigEndianUnicode использует кодировку UTF-16BE для преобразования байтов в строку. В UTF-16BE каждый символ кодируется двумя байтами, при этом первый байт содержит старший бит символа, а второй байт содержит младший бит. Таким образом, когда вы получаете строку из байтов, которые были закодированы в BMPString, и вы используете метод Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, то вы получаете строку, где каждый символ преобразован в два байта в кодировке UTF-16BE.

Знак Ḏ (U+1e0e) и другие подобные знаки, которые вы видите в начале вывода, являются результатом преобразования первого символа из двух байтов UTF-16BE в символ с кодом U+1e0e, который отображается как знак "Ḏ". Это произошло из-за того, что в BMPString используется кодировка с фиксированной длиной 2 байта, которое вызвало дополнительную обработку первого байта, что вызвало эти знаки в начале вывода.

Если вы хотите получить только текст, который следует после комментария в соответствии с OID 1.2.643.2.45.1.1.1, вы можете использовать подстроку строки после первого символа. Например:

```
string signedAttrString = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(signedAttrValue.RawData);
int commentIndex = signedAttrString.IndexOf("1.2.643.2.45.1.1.1");
string commentText = signedAttrString.Substring(commentIndex + "1.2.643.2.45.1.1.1".Length);
```

Этот код будет удалять комментарий и будет возвращать только текст после комментария.